# Fixed positioning overlap issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position

I am in a corner with this one. I have a layout with 2 containers. One of the containers represents a map (#main) and needs to stay in user view at all times, the other one (#sub) serves as a scroll-able content. Everything looks fine if content fits horizontally. However as soon as the horizontal bar appears (resize the window to replicate), the scroll-able content overlaps the fixed content and I am out of ideas how to fix it. I know of one way to fix it by positioning the fixed content absolutely instead and useing javascript to adjust its position from the top. Is there any way to fix it?

Sample code is below:

**Html:**

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="main">main</div>
    <div id="sub">
        <strong>Sub</strong><br />
        sub<br />
        sub<br />
        sub
    </div>
</div>
```

**Css:**

```
#content {
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#main {
    position: fixed;
    width: 849px;
    height: 500px;
    background: red;
}
#sub {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    width: 350px;
    height: 3500px;
    background: green;
}
```

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/ncQFw/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments it sounds like not allowing the user to scroll will solve the issue:

```
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x:hidden;
 }
```

If you want them both to scroll you have to remove the fixed positioning:

```
#main {
position: relative;
width: 849px;
height: 300px;
background: red;
font-size: 50px;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 200px;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: it does not do anything for me. the green container still runs over the red, if you use the horizontal scrollbar

Comment: How do you intend to get to the right side if the screen has a small width?

Comment: it would be better if nothing overlapped and both containers whether scroll together or just be evenly hidden by the page sides. that is my problem

Comment: So you are ok with it not being accessible on a small width screen?  If that's the case just turn off the horizontal scroll.

Comment: Thank you, @lucuma. The `overflow-x:hidden` on the `body` was what I needed.

Comment: Something more complex you could check the width of the viewport and depending on that hide or show the sidebar (you'd need to use the window resize event to make sure and always check on resize).